# OSX NFS Monitor file copy progress

Tags: macos, nfs

In our particular scenario we have an OSX NFS server which accepts incoming video clips from an encoding device.

The encoding device starts "stream-writing" the clip to the NFS share and the server picks up the newly copied file and starts polling the file as it grows, waiting for it to finish uploading from the NFS client.

What I need to know is the exact time the NFS client has finished uploading the file, our current method of polling for the file size has a safety threshold of 10 seconds before it considers the file uploaded. This happens because the NFS copy can have delays in transmission due to network or other reasons.

`lsof` will not work for the NFS mount, neither will `nfsstat` or any other command line tool i've looked at...

So is there a way to reliably and timely know that the client has finished copying a file to the OSX NFS Server mount?